# Multidimensional random draw without replacement with 'predrawn' samples in pytorch

Tags: multidimensional-array, random, pytorch

I have an `(N, I)` tensor of `N` rows with `I` indices beween `0` and `Z`, e.g.,
`N=5, I=3, Z=100`:

```
foo = tensor([[83,  5, 85],
              [ 7, 60, 66],
              [89, 25, 63],
              [58, 67, 47],
              [12, 46, 40]], device='cuda:0')
```

Now I want to efficiently add `X` random additional *new* indices (i.e., not yet included in the tensor!) between `0` and `Z` to the tensor, e.g.:

```
foo_new = tensor([[83,  5, 85,  9, 43, 53, 42],
                  [ 7, 60, 66, 85, 64, 22,  1],
                  [89, 25, 63, 38, 24,  4, 75],
                  [58, 67, 47, 83, 43, 29, 55],
                  [12, 46, 40, 74, 21, 11, 52]], device='cuda:0')
```

The tensor would in the end have in each row `I+X` unique indices between `0` and `Z`, where `I` indices are the ones from the initial tensor, and `X` indices are uniform randomly drawn without replacement from the remaining indices `{0...Z}\{I(n)}`, where `{I(n)}` are the inidices of the nth row.

So it's like a multidimensional random draw without replacement from indices `0` to `Z`, where the first `I` draws (in each row) are enforced to result in the indices given by the initial tensor.

How would I do this efficiently, especially with potentially large `Z`?

What I tried so far (which was quite slow):

```
device = torch.cuda.current_device()
notinfoo = torch.ones((N,I), device=device).byte()
N_row = torch.arange(N, device=device).unsqueeze(dim=-1)
notinfoo[N_row, foo] = 0
foo_new = torch.stack([torch.cat((f, torch.arange(Z, device=device)[nf][torch.randperm(Z-I, device=device)][:X])) for f,nf in zip(foo,notinfoo)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use first `numpy` [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to get samples with `replace=False` for without replacement sampling.
and then concat both using [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cat)

```py
import numpy as np
foo_new = torch.tensor(np.random.choice(100 , (5,4), replace=False))   # Z = 100
foo_new = torch.cat((foo, foo_new), 1)

foo_new
tensor([[83,  5, 85, 56, 83, 16, 20],
        [ 7, 60, 66, 43, 31, 75, 67],
        [89, 25, 63, 96,  3, 13, 11],
        [58, 67, 47, 55, 92, 70, 35],
        [12, 46, 40, 79, 61, 58, 76]])
```

Comment: That would produce duplicates in foo_new, as e.g. seen in your last row. I need the tensor to consist of unique numbers in each row, i.e. the added random numbers must be drawn a) without replacement, b) without yielding the numbers in the respective row of the initial tensor foo

Comment: foo_new can still have same indices as foo, so there can still be duplicates in the concatenated array. 
Also I was hoping for a pytorch solution.

Comment: Yes got it. Sorry   